# Stopping new points being added by Create Features of ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: editing, arcgis-pro

I am using Create Features from the Edit tab of ArcGIS Pro 2.1.2, and am using the Point construction tool to add multiple points (not multipoints).

When I want to stop adding points I expected to be able to click F2 or right-click and choose Finish.

The help on [Create point and multipoint features](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/editing/create-point-and-multipoint-features.htm#GUID-17AF9E1E-1C83-476A-BFC9-E53F9E86232F) is a little ambiguous on this but when I want to stop adding points I expected to be able to click F2 or right-click and choose Finish.

However, when I click F2 nothing happens (I still seem to be in the middle of adding new points) and right-clicking on or away from any of the points just added does not offer Finish in the one item context menu.

I think this behaviour may have changed from the last ArcGIS Pro version that I used to add points but, in any event, is there an obvious way to stop creating new point features that I am overlooking?

Answer (score 1):

As [commented by @MichaelStimson](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/283820/stopping-new-points-being-added-by-create-features-of-arcgis-pro?noredirect=1#comment454080_283820), it seems like the only way to stop adding points is by changing the active tool.

In my case the next thing that I wanted to do was to select the points that I had just added, so I clicked on the Select tool, and then used Shift and clicks to do that.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did.

-Went to the "Map" pane.
-Then within "Navigate", you will see the "Explore" button.
-Click on it and you will no longer add points to your map.